# Best way to populate a new attribute (new database column) of existing Rails models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I've just added a new column to an existing table in my database:

```
class AddMoveableDateToDocument < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :documents, :moveable_date, :datetime
  end
end
```

In my Rails model I want the `moveable_date` attribute to be set to a default value upon creation, and the application will be able to change this date later.  So, something like:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_moveable_date
  def set_moveable_date
    self.moveable_date ||= self.created_at
  end
end
```

Now, the existing models that are already saved into the database will not have this `moveable_date` set yet (the value is `nil`).  How do I run through all my existing models and populate the `moveable_date` attribute with its default value?  What is the easiest/best practice way?  Can be in the application code itself, in the console, in the terminal, or otherwise.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will get a lot of opinionated answers on this one. Some will suggest the console, some will suggest a one-time rake task.

I would suggest doing it as part of the migration that adds the column. After adding the column, you can run `Document.reset_column_information` so that the Rails app picks up on your new column, and then iterate through the existing document records and set the moveable date as appropriate.

Or if it's as simple as setting the moveable date to the created_at date, you can use something like `Document.update_all("moveable_date = created_at")` instead of iterating over them.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I think `Document.reset_column_information` is what I need, except putting it in the migration file seems to do nothing, as does typing it in the console.  The attribute is still `nil`.  Can you clarify on the exact usage of this method?

Comment: all it does is make Rails aware of your new column. If you dont do it, in your migration when you instantiate Document objects they will not have a `moveable_date` field.

Comment: Oh, so it does not populate it with the default value (for example by calling the `before_create` hook)?  And if I want to do that, I'll have to do that in the migration, in addition to `reset_column_information`, is that the correct interpretation?

Answer (score 0):

That's a good suggestion!

Another way is to add the line `before_save :set_moveable_date` to your model. It won't accomplish the transition immediately, but if your data is updated on a regular basis, it'd work.

Comment: This won't work in my particular application - I'm going to have to have it set right away, otherwise other parts of my application will break.  Thanks for the suggestion though!